# Permissions on a webserver for pmwiki

Tags: security, permissions

I want to install pmwiki on a webserver but I'm not sure which files need which permission.
Can someone point me to a good guide about Owner/Group/Other and Read/Write/Execute permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=pmwiki+file+permissions ([also](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/FilePermissions))